# How to save an image from RGB pixels array?

Tags: c#, image

Recently I [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10127871/1306322) how to save an image as bytes (RGB values in a text file), and now I'd like to know how to create a perfectly valid image from array of RGB values.

Comment: Can't you use the [constructor that takes dimensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we6s1x3.aspx), read your files, and call `SetPixel` on each of the pixels?

Comment: I don't have any files, I only have a 2d array of pixels' RGB values, what do I do next? (edit: didn't see the second comment, trying now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the approach mentioned by @dasblinkenlight:

```
int width = 1; // read from file
int height = 1; // read from file
var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Canonical);

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
   for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
   {
      int red = 0; // read from array
      int green = 0; // read from array
      int blue = 0; // read from array
      bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, red, green, blue));
   }
```