# How can I get pixel data from a .PNG?

Tags: c#, bitmap, unity-game-engine, png

**Without** using System.Drawing?

I have a C# application that receives a list of filepaths pointing to a number of .PNG files. I would like to extract an array of pixel (color) data from the image, but I am having trouble determining the best way to extract that.

I had originally hoped to be able to use System.Drawing, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10128284/355682), but I am unable to access System.Drawing, since my application (Unity3d) uses OpenGL (and therefore, is incompatible with System.Drawing)

The [PngBitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapdecoder%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) is likewise out of reach of the application. Is there any other way I can extract the data I'm interested in, short of writing my own PNG Decoder?

Comment: Perhaps [PngCs](https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/) fits the bill?

Comment: *Incompatible with `System.Drawing`* sounds funny. You don't necessary have to *draw* with it, but you still can include it and use (for things like creating/loading bitmap and reading its pixels), no?

Comment: @Sinatr No, I don't have access to the DLL at all.

Comment: Oh surely you [can have](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/53170/using-drawing-package-like-systemdrawing.html), when you really need to.

Comment: @Sinatr As far as I know, `dll`s can only be included like that if one has a Unity Pro license. (I do not, or I would have tried that method, as I did discover it in my searching.).

Comment: Why is [Texture2D.LoadImage](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html) not working?

Comment: @Jessy I did not know if its existence. I'd repost that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Unity, then you have access to their API which does exactly what you need.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels32.html

Comment: I am using `byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PATH);` in conjunction with LoadImage, but the loaded texture is coming in darker than the .PNG is saved as (comparing RGB values directly). Any clue why that'd be the case? It *is* working otherwise.

Comment: Sounds like you've got gamma or color space info in your PNG; LoadImage doesn't respect either, as far as I know, so you'll have to bake both.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to save the .pngs to remove that? I don't do much work with images, and I have no idea if something like that was added (or how).

Comment: I've only worked with profiles; apparently PNG supports gamma metadata, but I don't know how to work with it. On OS X, you can see the "Color Profile" under the "More Info" disclosure triangle, in the file info panel. If you don't have a profile, then I'm stumped, but if you do, you can just open the file in Photoshop and re-save, unchecking "Embed Color Profile" at the bottom of the save dialog.

Comment: Did some googling, gamma was being set; as you say, loadImage does not do gamma correction, so that **was** the difference. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I didn't. Rather, I *un* baked the source image, removing the gamma bytes from the PNG entirely via [this program](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/). That made the dynamic load equivalent to the editor load. It's unideal, but at least it confirmed what was actually happening with LoadImage.