# Reading BMP image from file and convert it into array in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-2010

I need code to read an image from a file and convert the image into an array of integers. The format of image is `BMP` and I'm using `vb.net-2010`

Answer (score 1):

You can find a similar question and valuable answers (although the question and answers are for c# i think they will help you to understand the solution)  at : [How can I read image pixels' values as RGB into 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127871/how-can-i-read-image-pixels-values-as-rgb-into-2d-array)

First you need to load the file to a System.Drawing.Bitmap object. Then you can read pixel values using GetPixel method. Note that every pixel data includes a Color value. You can convert this value to an integer value using ToArgb() method.

```
Imports System.Drawing;
...

Dim img As New Bitmap("C:\test.JPG")
Dim imageArray (img.Width, img.Height) As Integer   
Dim i, j As Integer
For i = 0 To img.Width
   For j = 0 To img.Height
      Dim pixel As Color = img.GetPixel(i,j)
      imageArray (i,j) = pixel.ToArgb()
   Next j
Next i
...
```

and the case storing a 2D array to a BMP object(Assuming you have a 100x100 2D array imageArray)

```
Imports System.Drawing;
...

Dim img As New Bitmap(100,100)
Dim i, j As Integer
For i = 0 To img.Width
   For j = 0 To img.Height
      img.SetPixel(i,j,Color.FromArgb(imageArray(i,j)))
   Next j
Next i
...
```

Comment: plz ...If I want to execute storing a 2D array as a BMP image file ? How can I do?

Comment: The compiler give this error......Error  Argument not specified for parameter 'y' of 'Public Sub SetPixel(x As Integer, y As Integer, color As System.Drawing.Color)'.    ..... How can I solve the problem? Gokhan

Comment: Excuse me that line should be : img.SetPixel(i,j,Color.FromArgb(imageArray(i,j)))
Corrected in answer